# Re-index data more than one in Apache Druid

Tags: streaming, druid

I want to get last one hour and day aggregation result from druid. Most queries I use includes ad-hoc queries. I want to ask two question;

**1-** Is a good idea that ingest all raw data without rollup? Without rollup, Can I re-index data with multiple times?. For example; one task reindex data to find unique user counts for each hour, and another task re-index the same data to find total count for each 10 minutes.

**2-** If rollup enabled to find some basic summarizes, this prevent to get information from the raw data(because it is summerized). When I want to reindex data, some useful informations may not found. Is good practise that enable rollup in streaming mode?

Answer (score 1):

1. Whether to enable roll-up depends on your data size. Normally we
   keep data outside of druid to replay and reindex again in the
   different data sources. If you have a reasonable size of the data
   you can keep your segment granularity to be hours/day/ week/month
   ensuring that each segment doesn't exceed the ideal segment size (
   500 MB recommended ). And query granularity to the none at index
   time, so you can do this unique and total count aggregation at query
   time.

   You can actually set your query granularity at the index time to be
   10 mins and it can still provide you uniques in 1 hr and total count
   received in 1 hr.

   Also, you can index data in multiple data sources if that's what you
   are asking. If you are reindexing data for the same data source, it
   will create duplicates and skew your results.
2. It depends on your use case. Rollup will help you better performance
   and space optimization in druid cluster. Ideally, I would suggest
   keeping your archived data separate in replayable format to reuse.